# How to retrieve contents from a uploaded file

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, file-get-contents

I am using cakephp framework. I would like to retrieve the contents of the uploaded file and store it in the database. I want to be able to search the content of the uploaded file.

I was made aware that file_get_contents would work for plain .txt files. But all my documents are .docx and .pdfs. Is there any solution I could use.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search got me this:

http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php

It appears you can search those files but it requires some additional packages.